# Scrapy / Python - url should be call multiple times (thanks to a loop). Called only one time. (dont_filter is not working)

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy, web-crawler

I'm not sure to understand how `scrapy` works. I did a crawler that is working almost perfectly. I have a list of dict. (config.products) these dict contains a POST that have to be sent in the function `initial_search`. So the `initial_search` has to be called multiple times, but right now the POST sent by `initial_search` is made only one time and the crawler is closing itself. I added `dont_filter = True` but this changes nothing. Does anyone know what is wrong?

```
def parse(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        meta={'product':config.products[0]},
        callback=self.initial_search
    )


def initial_search(self, response):
    config.actualProduct = response.meta['product']
    if config.products.index(config.actualProduct) == 0:
        config.savedResponse = response

    # The second time, the request is not made. (even with dont_filter=True)

    return scrapy.FormRequest(
        url=response.url,
        formdata=dictArgs,
        meta={'dictArgs': config.actualProduct},
        dont_filter = True,
        callback=self.other_function
    )

def other_function(self, response):
    return scrapy.FormRequest(
        url=response.url,
        formdata=dictArgs,
        meta={'dictArgs': config.actualProduct},
        callback=self.other_function2
    )

def other_function2(self, response):
        nextPosition = config.products.index(config.actualProduct) + 1

        # Checking if we have another dict to post

        if nextPosition < len(config.products):
            config.savedResponse.meta['product'] = config.products[nextPosition]
            self.initial_search(config.savedResponse)
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: is this line correct? `meta={'product':config.products[0]},`, you have a list of products but you're sending the first record everytime your parse is called

Answer (score 0):

In fact you are not calling your `initial_search` in `other_function2` properly. Here is how it should be look like:

```
def other_function2(self, response):
        nextPosition = config.products.index(config.actualProduct) + 1

        # Checking if we have another dict to post

        if nextPosition < len(config.products):
            config.savedResponse.meta['product'] = config.products[nextPosition]
            yield scrapy.Request(
                config.savedResponse,
                meta={'product':config.products[nextPosition]},
                callback=self.initial_search
                )
```

Comment: Hi Nima. Thank you for your response. But why should i used scrapy.Request at this level ? I mean i just want to call the function initial_search. I don't want to make an http request

Comment: By the way, initial_search i well called. it's just that the "return scrapy.FormRequest" is not made a second time... :/

Comment: first reason : your `initial_search` is a spider and receive a response after a request.

second reason : your initial_search extract a meta value that comes to this function. If you don't sent the meta value through your request, how it is going to extract it?!!!

third reason : You should use `scrapy.Request` because you don't have any form data to send to the initial_search